# Yandex Map 2.1: Как установить значения балунов для каждой точки маршрута?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Делаю, как описано в руководстве, [вот так](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_custom_balloon_layout).

Скажите, а как сделать, чтобы при каждой клике точек маршрутов (А, Б, С...) открывалась
[вот такая форма](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.0/geoobject_contextmenu) и  чтобы изменить контент, хинт выбранного баллуна?

Спасибо за любые подсказки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
multiRoute.events.add('contextmenu', function (e) {
    if(['startWayPoint', 'finishWayPoint', 'wayPoint'].indexOf(e.get('target').options.getName()) != -1) {
        //e.get('target')

        // Если меню метки уже отображено, то убираем его.
        if ($('#menu').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#menu').remove();
        } else {
            // HTML-содержимое контекстного меню.
            var menuContent = '<div id="menu">...</div>';

            $('body').append(menuContent);

            $('#menu').css({
                left: e.get('position')[0],
                top: e.get('position')[1]
            });

            //...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: вопрос не про placemark, а именно маршруты, multiRoute.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd у вас в вопросе именно про сам маршрут ничего нет. Вам нужно, чтобы у каждой точки маршрута открывалась форма правой кнопкой?

Comment: да, при правой клике точек маршрута(А,В,С,и .тд.) открывался какая нибудь форма для редактирования хинта, балун контента этой точки. Ваш пример подойдет для placemark.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd обновил. Вообще, к слову, всегда думал, что документация карт ужасно выполнена, ничего непонятно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то, что надо. Для интереса спрошу: у объекта multiRoute есть ли хинты, балун контенты (как у placemark-ов)?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd если честно, то не знаю. Я вообще с трудом нашел, какие параметры может принимать метод `get()`